# Delivery has not yet begun for this mailing

Tags: civimail, cron-job

when i send mail (**Mailing-> New Mailing**) the mail won't send and i get this message when i view the mail report

> Delivery has not yet begun for this mailing. If the scheduled delivery
>   date and time is past, ask the system administrator or technical
>   support contact for your site to verify that the automated mailer task
>   ('cron job') is running - and how frequently.

The Send **Scheduled Mailings**  from **Administer-> System Setting-> Scheduled Jobs** is enabled and when i **Execute now** manually it works fine. The **Send test** functionality also work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set up cron? All Scheduled Jobs are executed by cron.

http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs

Comment: i just enabled the Scheduled Mailings and there seems to be no parameter needed for that. is there any thing else i need to set up ?

Comment: You need to set up a cron job to run the scheduled jobs.  This is created outside of CiviCRM.  Details are in the link above.  Also see: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviMail+Installation

Comment: ah, it seems that i had problem with my host. Thank you very much